# GeoServer SSL certificate

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, ssl

How can I add a new PostGIS Store with SSL activation and the installation of certificates?

Currently it appears that GeoServer does not support this feature.

Comment: Please don’t use ALL CAPS in your title.

Answer (score 1):

There is a drop down box that allows you to set how to handle SSL on the PostGIS Datastore page:

[image]

From that you can select:

- Disable
- Allow
- Prefer
- Require
- Verify CA
- Verify All

depending on your requirement. The default is `disable` as SSL slows down requests to and responses from the database.

Comment: thanks but how can i install PEM certificates?

Comment: That's not really a GIS problem, may server overflow can help with that

Comment: My need is to install the certificates. How can I do it on Geoserver?

Comment: GeoServer doesn't care about certificates provided you have correctly set up SSL on postgis.